# Meaning of "netinet" in socket programming

Tags: c

What are the meanings of "netinet" and "in" in "#include <netinet/in.h>" ?

Answer (score 3):

"#include `<netinet/in.h>`

The header file in.h contains constants and structures needed for internet domain addresses."

As quoted at http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm

Answer (score -2):

It means "Internet"... obvious really.

Comment: Sorry, My English is not very well. I don't understand why "netinet" means "Internet".

Comment: Presumably it was named that way to signify that the directory contains networking headers ("net"), more specifically for the internet protocols ("inet").